# Truncated to the minute

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have written this code in my "Azure Stream Analytics" job.

```
SELECT
    DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp) AS WinStart,
    System.TimeStamp AS WinEnd,
    turnstile,
    COUNT(*) AS entries
INTO [output-blobstorage]
FROM [input-iot] TIMESTAMP BY entrytime
GROUP BY turnstile,  SlidingWindow (duration(second, 60))
```

I would like to have "WinStart" and "WinEnd" truncated to minute.

For exempl: If WinStart is "2018-06-08T18:15:01.5160000Z" i would like to have "2018-06-08T18:15:00.0000000Z"

This is my result file :

[image]

In other hand I would like to group by my result by "turnstile" and SlidingWindows based in minute.

But now I have secound and mi-sec in both first columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe combine two - Decomposing the date using [DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/datepart-azure-stream-analytics) and composing it back using [DateTimeFromParts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/datetimefromparts-azure-stream-analytics) and using zero for the seconds and milliseconds.

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy,WinStart), 
     DATEPART(mm,WinStart),DATEPART(dd,WinStart), DATEPART(hh,WinStart), 
     DATEPART(mi,WinStart), 0, 0) As WinStartRounded
```

Or do you want the [HoppingWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/azure/stream-analytics/reference/hopping-window-azure-stream-analytics) instead of SlidingWindow? so that the windows aligned to a 1 minute boundary:

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with following query

```
        SELECT
                DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                    DATEPART(yyyy,DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp)), 
                    DATEPART(mm,DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp)),
                    DATEPART(dd,DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp)), 
                    DATEPART(hh,DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp)), 
                    DATEPART(mi,DateAdd(minute,-1,System.TimeStamp)), 0, 0)
                  As WinStart,
                DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                    DATEPART(yyyy,System.TimeStamp), 
                    DATEPART(mm,System.TimeStamp),
                    DATEPART(dd,System.TimeStamp), 
                    DATEPART(hh,System.TimeStamp), 
                    DATEPART(mi,System.TimeStamp), 0, 0) As WinEnd,
                turnstile,
                COUNT(*) AS entries
        INTO [output-blobstorage]
        FROM [input-iot] TIMESTAMP BY entrytime
        GROUP BY 
            turnstile, 
            HoppingWindow (duration(second, 60),hop(second, 60))
```

[image]